# Avoid TIME_WAIT connections

Tags: netstat, time-wait

When I use netstat command it shows..

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:18056             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:16683             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:16701             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:16888             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:16832             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:17725             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:17682             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:17414             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:17606             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:17737             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:16632             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:16825             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:17807             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:17715             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:17304             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:17217             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:18098             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:17624             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:17734             localhost:mysql             TIME_WAIT
```

Time_wait connection is around 2000.

To avoid this I added `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=30` to `/etc/sysctl.conf`

But still I have some problem,,how to avoid it?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what problem you are having! Are you running out of local ports?

Comment: I want to reduce these TIME_WAIT connections ....

Comment: That's not a problem.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, See "[problems with TIME_WAIT](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1803566/632951)".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

TIME_WAIT exists for a reason and the reason is that TCP packets can be delayed and arrive out of order.  Messing with it will cause extra broken connections when they ought to have succeeded.  There's an [excellent explanation of all of this here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html).

Your problem is that you are not reusing your MySQL connections within your app but instead you are creating a new connection every time you want to run an SQL query.  This involves not only setting up a TCP connection, but then also passing authentication credentials across it.  And this is happening for every query (or at least every front-end web request) and it's wasteful and time consuming.

If you don't know how to enable persistent MySQL connection pooling in whatever language you are using, StackOverflow would be a good place to ask.

Comment: time_wait is a problem or not ??? you mean I am opening a connection but not closing it??

Comment: TIME_WAIT means a connection is closed (FIN packets have been sent) but we're holding the ports in reserve in case some more packets come through due to delays.  It also means you can't reuse that combination until it times out.  On Linux, only the ports matter and you can't reuse them even on a different IP address.  You can have about 30,000 before you run into problems and you can increase the ephemeral port range to delay dealing with that.

Comment: ok..I got you point. Last question- as you said 'time-wait means connection is closed but we are holding the ports..'  Can we reduce this holding time ???

Comment: You can, but it is not needed. If you want a very simple overview of what TIME_WAIT is, see the diagram in this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/450055/lot-of-fin-wait2-close-wait-last-ack-and-time-wait-in-haproxy

Comment: You can avoid the TIME_WAIT state altogether if you avoid the "active close" action however if you are creating TCP connections to yourself (such as you are here with MySQL on localhost) then one end of the connection or the other will have to initiate closing the connection.  Keeping these connections open is by far the best solution.